# How to De format the DateTime in flutter?

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I have formatted the date in flutter with specific format like "01-Jan-2000", Now How can I convert it back to the DateTime in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateFormat` like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateTime dateTime = dateFormat.parse("01-Jan-2000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). You can solve this in one line of code

```
DateTime dateTime = Jiffy.parse("01-Jan-2000", pattern: "dd-MMM-yyyy").dateTime;
```